# Child routing in Angular 5 not working

Tags: angular

I am having trouble routing in Angular 5.

I would like to support the following URL's

This one works:

```
/post
```

This one doesn't, it redirects me to my NotFoundComopnent

```
/post/test-post-title
```

My AppRoutingModule

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'post', loadChildren: 'app/feature/post/post.module#PostModule' },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },

];

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My PostRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PostHomeComponent,

        children: [
            { 
                path: ':slug', component: PostDetailComponent 
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class PostRoutingModule { }
```

**Updated to show the PostDetailComponent**

```
export class PostDetailComponentimplements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('slug');
    console.log(id)
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you nesting `<router-outlet>` for the children? Also can `enableTracing` in the config https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: Could you also show what your PostComponent template looks like?

Comment: I'm not nesting router-outlet, I only have one in the application

Comment: I've updated the question with my PostComponent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you define a child route using "children: [{ ... }]" as in your PostRoutingModule, you must have a router outlet inside your PostHomeComponent for this child component to be injected in.

In other words, if Component B is child of Component A, you can't expect to inject them both into the same router outlet that you have on app level.

Either, have a router outlet inside PostHomeComponent - this may or may not be what you want as you would end up displaying both Parent and Child components at the same time.

Or, change your routes to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PostHomeComponent
    },
    { 
        path: ':slug', component: PostDetailComponent 
    }

];
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but something is still not working.  If I change the 2nd path in your example to just path: 'test' then /post/test gives me a 404 (ie, doesn't even show my not found component

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue, you might want to check how you set up your routes, You don't have to set the **component** on the parent route.

**Wrong**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PostHomeComponent,

        children: [
            { 
                path: ':slug', component: PostDetailComponent 
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**Right**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'post',

        children: [
            { 
                path: '', component: PostHomeComponent,
            },
            { 
                path: ':slug', component: PostDetailComponent 
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [

{ path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},

{ path: 'post', component: 'PostHomeComponent'},

   children: [

              { path: 'test-post-title', component: 'PostDetailComponent'},

             ],

{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },

];
```

But remember to include a `<router-outlet>` inside your parent component i.e. PostHomeComponent in your case and inside your `<router-outlet>` angular will load your child component i.e. PostDetailComponent. Hope this helps.......if still things are unclear checkout this link [Introduction to Angular Routing](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing). It includes

1. Basic Routing
2. Nested Routing
3. Route Parameters